# Hiding my app on my website

Tags: information-hiding

Right now I have an application on my website that users can easily download from my website,  is there a way to hide or make it really hard to be able to find my application, so people can't just add /files/App.exe into the end of my domain to get my app? What do you recommend?

Comment: Your website is in PHP or ASP.NET or anything else ?? What have u tried so far??

Comment: `/files/NotTheApp.exe`?

Comment: You could always hide it outside the website root. For example,a directory above,and a folder such as **data**, have a programming script in the website root, whether PHP, ASP.NET (or whatever other language you are using), and have a secret parameter input to that script that would allow the script to be downloaded only with that secret word/words as an input to a given parameter: i.e. `downloadfile.script?secretfile=true`. When called with this parameter,the download of the application would be set up.As a bonus,you can also use this script to log the dl when,IP,etc if you need to track.this

Comment: I'll try this thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding your exe could be accomplished by

1. Create a unique identifier (perhaps a GUID)
2. Associate this with a file name for download and an expiration date (in a DB, perhaps)
3. Create a page that takes the unique ID as a parameter
4. Have this page check the DB for the unique id and ensure it hasn't passed the expiration date
5. Send the file to the client, setting Content-Disposition header to attachment

If you are using [ASP.NET this example will help you](http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/08/downloading-any-file-to-the-browser-part-ii-using-asp-net/)

Answer (score -1):

If u are using asp.net create a httphandler and map it in your web.config to the path of app.exe.. and just do response.write("get out") and log the details of the request.....equivalents are available on all popular platforms...