# Hide certain pages on website

Tags: javascript, php, html

There are some pages on my website where I don't want users to know the address of the certain page there on, is there any way to make it so that when they go to this certain page it will just be like www.example.com/# or something like that?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how will the user get to the page in the first place?

Comment: anything to do with your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389533/hiding-my-app-on-my-website

Comment: and why the javascript tag? if you're looking for a JS solution, that will fail once somebody disables that functionality for their browser

Comment: What's your real motive?

Comment: You can perhaps display the page within a popup. The [features for `open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) include `location=false` for not displaying the address/location input/bar. You can also obscure the address, navigating to paths containing keys/ids/codes that your server can lookup to respond with the intended content (similar in manner to the `/questions/{id}` used by SO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just redirect them with the location header. I should note that if it is in the public_html folder of your web server, then its NOT SECURE, by any means, no matter what php code you put ahead of the file.

To hide a file/path just put it one folder before the public docs and access it from there.

Insert this into the start of your page.

```
<?php header('Location: yourdomain.url'); 
      exit(); //Thanks Drixson Oseña
?>
```

Comment: don't forget to follow up an `exit(); or die();` function